# Runs fine in Atom but Runtime error(sigsegv) in codestudio compiler

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

The pattern to print if n=5 is

1 2 3 4 5

11 12 13 14 15

21 22 23 24 25

16 17 18 19 20

6 7 8 9 10

if anyone can tell me why and where is the overflow/segmentation fault.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
    
vector<string> printPattern(int n)
{
    int matrix[n][n];
    int i=0;
    int j=n-1;
    int k=1;
    while(i<=j)
    {
        int x=0;
        while (x <n&& i<=j) 
        {
            matrix[i][x]=k;
            k++;
            x++;
        }
        i++;
        int y=0;
        while(y<n && i<=j)
        {   
            matrix[j][y]=k;
            k++;
            y++;
        }
        j--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <=n-1; j++)
        {
            cout<< matrix[i][j];
            if (j < n - 1)
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Its a 2D array approach to a pattern problem in codingninja's codestudio interview problems.

Comment: This is not even standard C++: You should not use  `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and for `int matrix[n][n];` , `n` should be a compile time constant. This shows me that codingninja is not doing a good job of teaching you C++. Replace your matrix with `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`  and then use `.at(index)` instead of `[index]` operator. My bet is that your code runs out of bounds somewhere. Another option is to use a debugger

Comment: Better sources to learn cpp from are : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date with the latest guidelines.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)` the idiomatic way of writing the condition would be `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: This code appears to be GNU++, and not C++.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your logic works.

The code is not C++ and the function does not return a value. This might cause the trouble.

The task is not described very well, so, it is unknown how the function is called by `main()` or some other function. If the function is called with negative values, it will also crash. It is not clear, why the function returns a `vector` of `string`s.

C++ does also not know VLAs (Variable Length Arrays). C++ compiler would not compile your `int matrix[n][n];` statement. a 2d-`vector`should be used instead.

Applying these fixes will lead to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> printPattern(int n)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        vector<vector<int>> matrix(n, vector<int>(n));
        //int matrix[n][n];
        int i = 0;
        int j = n - 1;
        int k = 1;
        while (i <= j)
        {
            int x = 0;
            while (x < n && i <= j)
            {
                matrix[i][x] = k;
                k++;
                x++;
            }
            i++;
            int y = 0;
            while (y < n && i <= j)
            {
                matrix[j][y] = k;
                k++;
                y++;
            }
            j--;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= n - 1; j++)
            {
                cout << matrix[i][j];
                if (j < n - 1)
                {
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return {};
}
int main() {
    for (int i =-2; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << "\n--------------------------------------\ni = " << i << "\n";
        printPattern(i);
    }
}
```

This should work.